# d3 datamaps US state map redraw only individual state when clicked

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, datamaps

I'm using the datamaps library to display the US map using d3.js

I would like to only display a state when it is clicked. How can I do this using d3 or datamaps library?

```
var map = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('container'),
    done: function(datamap) {
        datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
            alert(geography.properties.name);
        });
    }
});
```

I'm thinking about using the done callback (example shown above) to set the projection of the datamap. But it doesn't seem to be working at the moment.

Comment: seems to work here http://jsbin.com/baqacagune/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yeah the alert works. But that's the not the issue. How can I use the data callback function to only display that element (state or country) when it is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
                datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit')
                        .style('display', function(d){
                            return d.id === geography.id ? 'initial' : 'none'
                        });
                datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-arc')
                        .style('display', function(d){
                            //
                        });
                datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-bubble')
                        .style('display', function(d){
                            //
                        });
            });
```